# Page Items and Variables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    t.rowid
FROM
    table.column t
WHERE
    fullorderno LIKE SUBSTR('${ORD}$',1,8) || '%'
```

When I run this SQL query using DB visualizer it shows up a popup dialog for me to key in the ORD value but when I use this with Oracle-APEX and change the query to be this where I change the variable to the page item number it doesn't return a value. The region I am running this SQL query at in APEX is a classic report and page item is P12_NUM

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    t.rowid
FROM
    table.column t
WHERE
    fullorderno LIKE SUBSTR('${:p12_num}$',1,8) || '%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that be as simple as

```
... WHERE fullorderno LIKE SUBSTR(:P12_NUM, 1, 8) || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `:P12_NUM` instead of `:p12_num`. It's case sensitive.
2. Use `fullorderno LIKE SUBSTR('${' || :P12_NUM || '}$',1,8) || '%'`
3. In clause `FROM` there should be `scheme.table t` or just `table t` without column name.
4. Make sure that you have correct column names.

Summary:

```
SELECT
 t.*, rowid
FROM
 table t
WHERE
 t.fullorderno LIKE SUBSTR('${' || :P12_NUM || '}$',1,8) || '%';
```

Comment: Its still not showing anything . When I run it in DB Visualizer it gives me : 
**bold** Error setting value for variable 1 (') : java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index **

Comment: Adjusted answer to cover your comment.

Comment: :p12_num or P12_NUM is the same . It's not case sensitive within the SQL itself.